# Erro ao referenciar váriavel global

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma aplicação na qual tem uma webview, então criei um preloader para carregar em uma thread , agora preciso colocar o webview em outra thread , como poso fazer (erro no código ) ?

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Network;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ConectActivity extends Activity {


    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    public  boolean verificaConexao() {
        boolean conectado;
        ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            conectado = true;
        } else {
            conectado = false;
        }
        return conectado;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conect);
        // *** roda qnd abre - Augusto Furlan ***
        Boolean conect = verificaConexao();
        String url = "http://google.com";
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        //webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        webView.setVisibility(webView.GONE);

        WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SystemClock.sleep(25000);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showWebView();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(self.conect == true) {
                    webView.loadUrl(self.url);
                } else {webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/not-found.html");;}

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showWebView();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
        }



    private void showWebView() {
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Por que não colocou o código aqui ao invés de usar o pastebin?

Comment: pois ja estava la , por der mais pratico, mas posso colocar o codigo aqui, 1 min

Comment: Qual é o erro? Sugiro que [edit](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/94595/edit) sua pergunta e destaque qual é o erro.

Comment: na hora dentro da segunda thread ele nao permite eu usar self.url , nao permite acesso a global

Comment: Mas nem sempre todo mundo que poderá te ajudar tem acesso a esses links. É recomendável sempre postar a fonte do erro direto aqui e, para códigos extensos, postar no link externo pra quem quiser mais detalhes do seu código.

Comment: Ok desculpe, ja editei e coloquei o codigo

Comment: Tenho umas variaveis e preciso acessar para realizar a comparacao

Comment: Veja se a minha resposta atende ao que pretende.

Answer (score 0):

Se o que pretende é aceder aos atributos `conect` e `url` da classe *ConectActivity* deve fazê-lo de forma directa, usando os nomes delas.
A palavra `self`não existe em JAVA.

Para que esses atributos possam ser usados em uma *inner* classe necessitam, no entanto, de ser declarados como `final`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conect);

    final Boolean conect = verificaConexao();
    final String url = "http://google.com";

    ...
    ...
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(conect == true) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            } else {webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/not-found.html");;}

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showWebView();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: amigo nao sei por que colocou final apos o tipo na declaracao, mas mesmo assim nao funcionou e acusa erro

Comment: Quando dá erro seria bom dizer qual é. :)

Comment: Error:(77, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable conect
Error:(78, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable url

Comment: Essa variável que quer usar é o atributo `url` da classe *ConectActivity*?

Comment: sim, como esta no codigo, porem esta dentro da funcao protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: Onde o senhor julga que é o problema ?

Comment: Experimente declarar `conect` e `url` ao nível da classe, fora do método `onCreate()`

Comment: o erro no codigo parou, mas agora quando abre ele acusa q o app parou

Comment: Isso será por outra razão. No entanto não entendo porque dá erro estando a declaração dentro do onCreate().

Comment: oq vc acha pode ser ?

Comment: Sem saber qual é o erro não acho nada. Sendo isso outro problema deve criar nova pergunta onde deve postar o *LogCat* com o erro.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Fiquei sem saber se a minha resposta resolveu ou não o problema inicialmente colocada na pergunta.